# Model "Point on curve" constrain in simMechanics second generation Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape

I would like using simMechanics second generation to have a body following a predefined trajectory (like a circle). Then if i provide an external force the body must start moving constrained in the trajectory.

In simMechanics 1st generation was present the "point-on-curve" constraint, there is a way to model it in the 2nd generation?

Thank you in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In SimMechanics' Second Generation, you still have a `Point on Curve Constraint` block, search for it in the Simulink Library Browser. More info [here](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sm/ref/pointoncurveconstraint.html).